# Código R para teste de verossimilhança

Tags: r

Tenho um conjunto de dados para fazer uma regressão logística para a variável dependente "parto" que é qualitativa binária.

Com o comando abaixo consigo o modelo logístico univariado:

```
GLM.1 <- glm(parto ~ serie, family=binomial(logit), data=Dataset)
```

Com este outro comando abaixo consigo o valor de p do qui-quadrado do teste de razão de verossimilhança.

```
1-pchisq(GLM.1$null.deviance-GLM.1$deviance, GLM.1$df.null-GLM.1$df.residual)
```

Quais comandos devo usar para encontrar separadamente cada um dos seguintes componentes?

1. deviance
2. L(modelo reduzido)
3. L(modelo saturado)

Comment: Para isso tem de ter um conjunto de dados e uma distribuição de probabilidade. Clarifique a pergunta, por favor. (E já agora, que tipo de teste? Um teste de razão de verosimilhanças?)

Comment: Meu conjunto de dados contém uma amostra de mais de 400 indivíduos. Preciso fazer uma regressão logística para a variável dependente "parto" que é qualitativa binária. Tenho algumas variáveis independentes que também são qualitativas, com duas ou mais categorias. Então, preciso fazer o teste de razão de verossimilhança.

Comment: Faça uma pergunta mais completa, com trechos de código que você está utilizando e até disponibilize os dados (ou uma amostra deles), se possível. No stackoverflow, é sempre recomendável compartilhar um código mínimo reprodutível -- questões curtas e vagas assim acabam sendo penalizadas. 

Mas tentando contribuir substantivamente, recomendo que você dê uma olhada nessa resposta aqui: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/likelihood-ratio-test-in-r

Comment: Obrigada Rui Barradas e RogerioJB. Melhorei as perguntas. Espero que possam me ajudar!!

Comment: Obrigada Rui Barradas e RogerioJB. Consegui resolver o problema com o pacote lmtest usando a função lrtest(GLM.1) que tinha no link enviado pelo RogerioJB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora é mais fácil responder à pergunta. Basta ver a secção `Value` da página `?glm`.

```
L_sat <- GLM.1$deviance/(-2)
L_red <- GLM.1$null.deviance/(-2)
```

Nota ainda que é possível simplificar o cálculo do `p-value`, usando o argumento `lower.tail` que todas as funções distribuição do `R` têm. Isto pode ainda ser importante porque os erros de arredondamento são menores.

```
pchisq(GLM.1$null.deviance-GLM.1$deviance, GLM.1$df.null-GLM.1$df.residual, lower.tail = FALSE)
```